# Now Mongoose Cannot overwrite model once compiled

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, next.js, vercel

I'm using MongoDB Atlas to host the DB and just querying data with this severless function:

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

// models
import { Section } from "../../../models/Section";

// db connection
import { useDatabase } from "../../../middleware/useDatabase";

async function find(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  const { content } = req.query;
  const response = await Section.find({ contentType: content });
  res.send(response);
}

export default useDatabase(find);
```

The middleware `useDatabase` is configured like this:

```
import * as mongoose from "mongoose";
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

export const useDatabase = handler => async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  if (mongoose.connections[0].readyState) return handler(req, res);
  // Using new database connection
  await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  });

  return handler(req, res);
}
```

The first time I execute the query doing a fetch to the api, works well, then if I edit some code, save it and `now dev` recompile the code, I got this error when I do the query again:

```
MongooseError [OverwriteModelError]: Cannot overwrite `Section` model once compiled.
    at new OverwriteModelError (/home/andres/Documents/shooter-app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/overwriteModel.js:20:11)
    at Mongoose.model (/home/andres/Documents/shooter-app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:521:13)
    at Module../models/Section.ts (/home/andres/Documents/shooter-app/.next/server/static/development/pages/api/sections/[content].js:154:63)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/andres/Documents/shooter-app/.next/server/static/development/pages/api/sections/[content].js:23:31)
    at Module../pages/api/sections/[content].ts (/home/andres/Documents/shooter-app/.next/server/static/development/pages/api/sections/[content].js:198:73)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/andres/Documents/shooter-app/.next/server/static/development/pages/api/sections/[content].js:23:31)
    at Object.3 (/home/andres/Documents/shooter-app/.next/server/static/development/pages/api/sections/[content].js:233:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/andres/Documents/shooter-app/.next/server/static/development/pages/api/sections/[content].js:23:31)
    at /home/andres/Documents/shooter-app/.next/server/static/development/pages/api/sections/[content].js:91:18
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/andres/Documents/shooter-app/.next/server/static/development/pages/api/sections/[content].js:94:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:848:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at DevServer.handleApiRequest (/home/andres/Documents/shooter-app/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:420:28)
    at async Object.fn (/home/andres/Documents/shooter-app/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:350:37)
    at async Router.execute (/home/andres/Documents/shooter-app/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/router.js:42:32)
    at async DevServer.run (/home/andres/Documents/shooter-app/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:468:29) {
  message: 'Cannot overwrite `Section` model once compiled.',
  name: 'OverwriteModelError'
}
```

How can I solve it? Thank you!

Comment: I'm having the same issue, and it seems to be Next.js specific. Did you ever figure out a solution?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This happens when the development server tries to recompile your model  during *hot module replacement*.

You can prevent this from happening by changing your code to check whether the model has already been compiled when exporting it.

```js
export default mongoose.models['Section'] || mongoose.model('Section', SectionSchema);
```

Comment: This deserves a bit more up votes than it has. Thanks.

Comment: I ran into this when creating a test file for my API. The fact is that the file was being imported before in another module, hence the error, so doing the check solved it. Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: The only drawback here is that despite the Nextjs Team have a nice expample for this (https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-mongodb-mongoose/models/Pet.js) mongoose.models is not in their TypeScript definitions.

Comment: For anyone that comes across this: This method does work with hot module replacement in Next. However, you will get an error on statics. At least that's whats happening for me. The model that we are checking to see if it exists is not showing as the extended model with the static functions. So it displays your statics as not existing on the model. I'm sure someone with more knowledge can/will expand on this but it's worth noting that it's nothing wrong with your statics.